# plot multiple fit and predictions for logistic regression

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, regression

I am running multiple times a logistic regression over more than 1000 samples taken from a dataset. My question is what is the best way to show my results ? how can I plot my outputs for both the fit and the prediction curve?

This is an example of what I am doing, using the baseball dataset from R. For example I want to fit and predict the model 5 times. Each time I take one sample out (for the prediction) and use another for the fit.

```
library(corrgram)
data(baseball)

#Exclude rows with NA values
dataset=baseball[complete.cases(baseball),]

#Create vector replacing the Leage (A our N) by 1 or 0.
PA=rep(0,dim(dataset)[1])
PA[which(dataset[,2]=="A")]=1

#Model the player be league A in function of the Hits,Runs,Errors and Salary  
fit_glm_list=list()
prd_glm_list=list()
for (k in 1:5){
  sp=sample(seq(1:length(PA)),30,replace=FALSE)
  fit_glm<-glm(PA[sp[1:15]]~baseball$Hits[sp[1:15]]+baseball$Runs[sp[1:15]]+baseball$Errors[sp[1:15]]+baseball$Salary[sp[1:15]])    
  prd_glm<-predict(fit_glm,baseball[sp[16:30],c(6,8,20,21)])
  fit_glm_list[[k]]=fit_glm;prd_glm_list[[k]]=fit_glm
}
```

Comment: where is the "baseball" dataset?

Comment: @A.R What do you mean by "show my results"? Plot the distribution of  predictions? Plot the residuals? Plot other regression diagnostics? Something else?

Comment: @pteetor plot the distribution of predictions and residuals

Comment: There is some package that you loaded (and did not mention) that contains the baseball data. Maybe `corrgram`?

Comment: thanks @Seth, i though it was from the default datasets

Comment: @RicardoOliveros-Ramos library(corrgram)

Comment: This is not logistic regression! I tried it and `fit_glm$family` returns "gaussian".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

- `PA` is a subset of `baseball$League` but the model is constructed on columns from the whole  `baseball` data frame, *i.e.* they do not match.
- `PA` is treated as a continuous response when using the default family (gaussian), it should be changed to a factor and binomial family.
- `prd_glm_list[[k]]=fit_glm` should probably be `prd_glm_list[[k]]=prd_glm`
- You must save the true class labels for the predictions otherwise you have nothing to compare to.

My take on your code looks like this.

```
library(corrgram)
data(baseball)

dataset <- baseball[complete.cases(baseball),]

fits <- preds <- truths <- vector("list", 5)
for (k in 1:5){
  sp <- sample(nrow(dataset), 30, replace=FALSE)
  fits[[k]] <- glm(League ~ Hits + Runs + Errors + Salary,
                   family="binomial", data=dataset[sp[1:15],])    
  preds[[k]] <- predict(fits[[k]], dataset[sp[16:30],], type="response")
  truths[[k]] <- dataset$League[sp[1:15]]
}
plot(unlist(truths), unlist(preds))
```

The model performs poorly but at least the code runs without problems. The y-axis in the plot shows the estimated probabilities that the examples belong to league N, *i.e.* ideally the left box should be close to 0 and the right close to 1.

[image]